# What is the best way to load images in my React Native App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, native

I use Firebase for my backend but every time when the app request the image URL it loads very slow. How can I speed up this procedure? Or which CDN provider can I use in my React Native project to load images faster than now?

Thank you

I tried to request the URL from different sites but still slow load

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do not ask for the _Best_ of anything, that is subjective and will lead to opinionated answers. Also try do not ask multiple questions, be specific about your desired outcome and include the details of what you have tried. We need to know sizxe of images and the bandwidth or load times that you have measured. It will be useful to post the actual code you use to load the images and include a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, what I did was I reduced the image size hence reducing its file size. This will help your image to load faster.

The quality will drop a bit for sure, but as long as it looks nice on your phone it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image because RN Image doesn't support cache and loads an image every time you mount a component.